# AutoCompleteTextview ResourceNotFoundException within dialog

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a problem when creating an AutoCompleteTextView within a dialog

My code to create the view is

```
private void setPalleteOnClicks() {
    ImageButton newMethod = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.new_method);
    newMethod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AndroidPDStoreActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.method_creation);
            dialog.setTitle("New Method Creator");

            //String[] types = {"int", "double"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AndroidPDStoreActivity.this,R.id.autoComplete, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types));
            AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
            actv.setThreshold(1);
            actv.setAdapter(adapter);
            dialog.show();
        }

    });

}
```

My Xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    .... 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Return Type: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:dropDownHeight="100sp"
            android:text="" >

        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The exception i am getting is

```
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167): Process: com.android.pdstore, PID: 24167
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050024 type #0x12 is not valid
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2314)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1585)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1167)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:554)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1096)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:971)
08-14 14:11:14.524: E/AndroidRuntime(24167):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:953) .....
```

I have tried clean and deletion of R.java files as stated by other posts, but this did not help. The problem only occurs when the drop down menu actually needs to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(AndroidPDStoreActivity.this,R.id.autoComplete, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types));
```

As you can see the second parameter in the constructor of the `ArrayAdapter` you are supplying an id from your `AutoCompleteTextView` in the xml  which catch `Resources$NotFoundException`. It is expecting a layout for the instantiating the views not an id from `AutoCompleteTextView`.

[documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)):

```
The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.
```

**solution:**

you need to call the native android layout for `AutoCompleteTextView` to use as a layout for instantiating the views.

**sample:**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AndroidPDStoreActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types));
```

Comment: @WasiqKashkari +1 this post as well if it helps thank you. happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem related to multiple screen sizes where you have `layout-[qualifier]` folders? It may happen that you have the resource for one screen size and not for the other. If it is, you may want to move some of your layouts (the ones that will not change based on screen sizes) to the unqualified `layout` folder rather than keeping it in specific, size-based folders.